# Issue testing fclose return value

Tags: c, file

In order to have a cleaner way to test specific functions, I wanted to implement tests on the `fclose` function. But I had an issue when trying to write and re-read a Bitmap image.

In fact, I had a bug occuring when testing `fclose` this way:

```
assert(fclose(bmp_image) != EOF);
```

While the following code doesn't give any error:

```
int closing_ok = fclose(bmp_image);
assert(closing_ok != EOF);
```

With more tests, I saw this difference occurs only in write mode but not in read mode. Is it normal such a difference occurs ? Can someone explain me this difference ?

**EDIT:** 
I tried to get the error meaning with that code:

```
if(fclose(output_file) != EOF) {
    printf("ERROR: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

But it is also fine here and no error.

Comment: What is the issue exactly? Did it simply not get called?

Comment: @StoryTeller I suppose it is. It might not close the file properly...
This is not that big of an issue, I just don't understand this behaviour.

Comment: Your test in `if(fclose(output_file) != EOF)` should probably be `if(fclose(output_file) == EOF)` to print the error reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assert` is a macro that is replaced with a no op when compiled with `NDEBUG`. Roughly speaking, if you build a release version of your executable, the entire call to `fclose` is eliminated from the code.

That is a possible reason for why files may not be closed properly.

Answer (score 2):

[`assert()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html) has to be used with a scalar expression. That means you should not use a function in it.

You get this behavior because `fclose(bmp_image)` is evaluated twice. So it returns `EOF` on the second call, because the file is already closed.

You can test with this:

```
int my_fclose(FILE *file) {
  int ret = fclose(file);
  if (ret == EOF) {
    printf("ERROR: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  }
  else {
    printf("no problem\n");
  }
  fflush(stdout);
  return ret;
}

int main(void) {
  // bad
  assert(my_fclose(bmp_image) != EOF);
}
```

Comment: What is the difference to the code in the question? You also call a function in assert. And if `NDEBUG` is defined, your `my_fclose` function is also not called at all.

Comment: @Gerhardh It's always print something so the OP can see that the function is call twice. Maybe add a `fflush(stdout);`. To be sure.